# Does manually arresting criminals cause a drop in respect of their family?

Tags: tropico-4

I know that if I feel like arresting a random citizen just because I can, I will lose the respect of their family.  This is fair enough.

However, if I *manually* issue an arrest action on a citizen who is genuinely a criminal but hasn't been automatically arrested because my police force are incompetent and corrupt - do the criminal's family still take offence?

I haven't found a married criminal in ages to test it on.

Comment: "My husband/wife was arrested!" does crop up as an unhappy thought if you examine their spouse after the arrest; based on that I'd say it's probably at least a mild negative modifier... (Don't have access to the game right now or I'd check more thoroughly and put up an actual answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having *finally* found a married criminal to test this on, I can confirm that even though they are actually evil criminal masterminds having them manually arrested **does** give the thought "A member of my family was arrested" and a corresponding roughly 25% respect drop.

I would see if this happened when the police arrest crims off their own back, however they seem too incompetent to sort this out themselves.  I'll keep an eye out.